# Python: Is there a way to save a value in the try block and pass it onto the except block?

Tags: python, try-except

I want to accomplish the following:

I have a global variable x assigning to int(input('x: ')) in the try block, but I want to pass the value of x in the except block to alert the user that the specific value that he/she typed was invalid. It seems like the except block doesn't even recognize the value of x. I have even tried using a global variable x, but that is apparently not working. For example if I type an invalid value such as 'hello', I want to save the value 'hello' and pass it onto the except block to notify the user 'hello' is invalid. Expecting an integer. The result I  get instead is None is invalid because I initialized the global variable x to None.

```
global x
x = None

def main():
    global x
    x = get_int()
    print(f"x = {x}")

def get_int():
    global x

    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

        except ValueError:
            print(f"{x} is invalid. Expecting an an integer")
            # pass
        else:
            return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: i think its not possible since when the try fails on the x = int(input("Enter an integer: ")) the x value isnt set and therefore cant be printed in the except.

Comment: FYI: No reason for a global variable at all.

Answer (score 4):

The error is being thrown when the value returned by `input()` is being parsed into an integer by `int()`, so `x` is never actually assigned a value because it's `int()` that's throwing the exception.

Try doing it in two steps, where you get a value and then parse it, that way you can catch the `ValueException` raised by `int()`, but you have the value the user entered stored so you can display it back.

(As mentioned by @chepner, the `input()` should be outside that try block because it won't raise a `ValueError`.)

```
x = input("Enter an integer: ")
try:

    y = int(x)
except ValueError:
    print(f"{x} is invalid. Expecting an integer")
```

Comment: Better yet, put the assignment to `x` *before* the `try` statement, because it will not raise a `ValueError` that you plan to handle.

Comment: Oh. Wow. That was quick. That actually works. I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`x` isn't assigned due to the error, but you can capture the exception and display the error message, which is actually relevant.  Also, no need for a global variable:

```py
def main():
    x = get_int()
    print(f'{x=}')

def get_int():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Enter an integer: '))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer: hello
Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
Enter an integer: 5
x=5
```

Comment: I removed the global reference. I like your answer. I learned two new things from your answer: 1) I didn't know about f'{x=}. Now, I know. 2) capture the error message e from the interpreter itself so I don't have to create my own error message in the except block. Thank you so much.. (I tried giving you a point, but the site won't let me. I don't have 15 points yet. I just started.)